# How to restore some files from btrfs snapshot (created via timeshift) of encrypted home dir via ecryptfs

Tags: btrfs, snapshot, ecryptfs

I use Linux Mint 20 and Timeshift to create btrfs snapshots from @ and @home.
My home dir is encrypted. Timeshift also includes @home/.ecryptfs/ in the snapshots.

I'd like to take a look at some files contained in the snapshot.

How do I temporarily mount the snapshot via ecryptfs to be able to access the decrypted files?

I found that there is the script `ecryptfs-recover-private`. The manpage says that "The program can take a target encrypted directory on the command line."

But which directory should I use? In my (snapshotted) home there is the `.Private` and `.ecryptfs`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in a [comment to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/102257/592751), `ecryptfs-recover-private` can pass multiple `.Private` directories as arguments (and also `--rw` to [mount the directory writable in case you need this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/ecryptfs-recover-private.1.html)).

In fact, it looks for the "wrapped-passphrase" in `../.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`.

If you know your login passphrase, everything is fine:

```
$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private .Private
INFO: Found [.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: Y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] Y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [xxx] into the user session keyring
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.xxx].
```

EDIT: First, it did **not** work yet: The data mounted at `/tmp/ecryptfs.xxx` seems to be my *current* home dir, not the one from the snapshot

You need to be aware that there are sym links from `yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss/@home/user/.Private` to `/home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private/` and the same for `.ecryptfs` and they use the *absolute path* not a relative one ... well ...